# Git. Delete a branch

Tags: git

I have a "bugfix" branch on which there are already several commits (I did not post a branch to the server). If I delete this branch, then the commits will be lost in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Of course all the commits to that branch will be lost.
but you can do one thing make a new branch from that commit you can cherry pick the commit and make a new branch.

just take the sha of that commit and cheery pick into another branch 
checkout to master branch

`git checkout master`

and then cherry pick that commit

`git cheery-pick -x <sha of commit>`

now the commit is taken into master branch

now you can delete the branch you want to remove with

`git branch -D <branch-name>`

Comment: Thank you. This is the complete answer to my question.

Comment: "... all the commits to that branch will be lost." Not totally true, the commits will remain until they are garbage collected. A branch is just a pointer to a commit. If you remove the branch you remove the pointer only @ioprst.